# How do I save multiple MapAnnotations using this code?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, nsuserdefaults, mkannotation

In my mapview, the user can make his own map pin by tapping on the screen. He can set multiple pins.  However, my code for saving only saves the last pin he has made and not the previous ones. How do I make it save the previous ones as well?

```
- (void)addPinToMap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        return;

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.mapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate =
    [self.mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];

     NSMutableArray *pincoords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = { touchMapCoordinate.latitude, touchMapCoordinate.longitude };
[pincoords addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&coordinate objCType:@encode(CLLocationCoordinate2D)]];


    MapAnnotation *toAdd = [[MapAnnotation alloc]init];

    toAdd.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate;
    toAdd.title = @"Svampe Spot";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:toAdd];

    //Save pin section..

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:pincoords forKey:@"saveCoords"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

EDIT: So i made some changes. I made an NSMutable array and added the coordinates to it. However, the app terminates when trying to make a pin due to this: [NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert non-property list object.

Everytime i try to add coordinates to mutable array i seem to get that message, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: As the docs for `setObject:forKey:` say, object must be a NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.  NSValue is not supported so you get that error.  As the answer suggests, wrap the coordinate in an NSDictionary, add the dictionary to the array, and then save the array.  Also note that you only want to alloc+init the array if it doesn't already exist in NSUserDefaults (otherwise you'll again be storing only the last pin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you write a new pin to the user defaults, it overwrites the old one. Instead, write an NSArray or NSMutableArray to the user defaults and add/remove pins from it.

UPDATE:
First of all, the NSMutableArray needs to be copied from the user defaults, not alloc/inited. This way, the array will already contain the previously saved points in it:

```
NSMutableArray *pincoords = (NSMutableArray *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"saveCoords"];
```

This will return a mutable array with your previously saved coordinates.

As for the method you are using to store the coordinate in the array, I think you have the right idea, but I've personally never done it that way. NSArrays can only store objects, and CLLocationCoordinate2D is not an object (probably a C struct like NSRect, I've never used it before). It needs to be converted to a NSCoding compliant object, such as NSString, NSNumber, or NSDictionary. What you could do is create a function to manually enter the coordinate values (wrapped in an NSNumber) into a NSDictionary (using keys such as @"Lat" and @"Long" for your coordinates), and then store the NSDictionary in your mutable array.

Comment: I have tried to make a MutableArray, and added my pins to it, but everytime i get a "could not insert property" error.

Comment: Please post your code for inserting into a mutable array.  user2105505's suggestion should work.

Comment: Ok, i made some changes to the code above, including a mutable array and how i try to store it with nsuserdefaults.

Comment: I have been looking into using an NSString. However, the coordinates of my pins depend on where my user puts the pin, and therefore I do not have any specific coordinate value to use in an NSString or NSNumber. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: I think that you are misunderstanding what I mean. A CLLocationCoordinate2D is indeed a struct (it's in the Apple docs) with latitude and longitude of type CLLocationDegrees (a typedef of double). Store latitude in NSNumber* latDegrees = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:latitude];. Do the same with the longitude. Then create a new NSDictionary with two key-value pairs: @"Lat"-latDegrees and @"Long"-longDegrees. Now you have an NSCoding compliant coordinate dictionary that you can add to your array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I haven't been able to make it work yet, but you got me on the right path.